# Torch is installed but I'm unable to import it in a computer vision python project in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, torch, detectron

I'm working on a computer vision project using detectron2. I'm having trouble installing torch or importing it into my jupyter notebook. I'm working on a mac that is running MACOS Catalina, Python3 version in 3.8.2 and I'm using Anaconda for my Development environment. In the screenshot, it says torch is installed but it throws error while importing it
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed `torch` for python at `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`

but as you said yourself, you are

> using Anaconda for my Development environment

So if your jupyter notebook is really configured to use your python installation that came alongside anaconda, then you need to do

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

Note:

1. Make sure which python interpreter your jupyter is actually using by running

   `import sys; print(sys.executable)`
2. Make sure that you install `torch` for the correct `conda` environment (above command will also indicate which one that is)
3. Set the cudatoolkit version according to your needs. There is also a simple interface on the [official website](https://pytorch.org/) to get the correct command

Comment: Thanks, you're a lifesaver